# libfreetype6-dev and libpng

Tags: 16.04, 16.10, c++, official-repositories, libpng

I am using Ubuntu 16 and am having conflicts vis a vis libpng and libfreetype6-dev.

For development purposes, I **have** to use libpng16 (`libpng16-16`, `libpng16-dev`, `libpng16-devtools`). I also need to use `libfreetype6-dev`, else I get a compilation error saying that `ft2build.h` is missing.

When installing `libfreetype6-dev`, it removes libpng16 and puts libpng12 back in its place, and this causes other issues.

Is there a version of libfreetype that keeps libpng16 as a dependency?

Comment: You have tagged two different releases, and mention a third incorrectly (*yy* releases are used for specialist *snap* based releases like Ubuntu Core 16, you missed the word Core or didn't mean a *yy* release).  Are you using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?, Ubuntu 16.10? or Ubuntu Core 16?

Answer (score 1):

To make system working as you want you have to upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS.

Below are the [dependencies for 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfreetype6-dev):

> **Package: libfreetype6-dev (2.8.1-2ubuntu2)**
> depends
> ...
> **libpng-dev**  PNG library - development (version 1.6)

Compare with [dependencies for 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libfreetype6-dev).

Comment: unfortunately, that is not an option. thank you though